# Switch keyboards quickly

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note, keyboard-shortcuts

I've got a Samsung Galaxy Note with SlideIt installed which works wonderfully. But I can't write with my pen anymore. So how do I switch VERY QUICKLY to the Samsung keyboard and back?

Comment: Long-pressing the menu button won't bring up the keyboard?

Comment: @C.B. No, that calls up Google Now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue with my Note II.  The best solution I've found is the app [Quick Keyboard Switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appaholics.keyboardswitch&hl=en), which gives you a notification bar icon you can tap after pulling down to bring up a dialog box to switch KBs.  You can switch back the Samsung kb, and from there hit the handwriting input button to get back to pen input.

Comment: Your link is now broken.

Comment: @MarianD: hardly surprising, given that the answer is over five years old.

Comment: I didn't surprise, I stated it - partly for other users to prefer other answers, partly for you as an opportunity to edit your answer or update the link to possibly gain more reputation from it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little keyboard icon in the notification pane up top which appears when a text field get's entered. This can also be used to switch quickly. So It appears a third-party app is not necessary.